# Windows 10 - Mandatory installation of server's certificate on the client computer

Tags: windows-10, security, ssl, certificate, tls

There are 2 parts to my question, both related to SSL sites:

1. I want to configure my Windows OS to disallow browsing to any SSL sites whose server authentication certificate is not installed on my local computer. My browser is Chrome.
2. I want to disallow any programmatic API communications with SSL sites whose server authentication certificate is not installed on my local computer.

I want to do this to experiment with server authentication certificates on the client computer, and what errors users get when a client application makes an API call to an SSL server in a highly secure enterprise environment which requires installation of server's certificate on the client's computer.

My OS is Windows 10 Professional.

Comment: Which browser ?

Comment: Browser is Chrome. This is for the 1st part of the question. The 2nd part is about programmatic API call, which does not require browser.

Comment: In Windows, you cannot trust leaf certificates. Only CAs.

Comment: @AllSolutions - You never specify which browser in your question.  You should [edit] your question instead of having that relevant information contained in a comment

Comment: Done. Edited the question

Comment: Typically, firewall configurations are used for enterprise environments and would be how I would handle it. At the network level, disallow that machine from any communications not explicitly desired.

Comment: Ok. But for the ones which are allowed through the firewall, how do I ensure that they cannot be accessed without the site's certificate installed on the local computer?

Comment: I have seen enterprises asking for server's certificate. Just that I do not know how to configure or replicate the same environment on my system